# How JS treat function parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I know that in js functions are objects and As far as i understand objects have properties and methodes. But I don't know how the JS engine handle function parameters?(asthey aren't accessible like properties).
In the code below:

```js
function func(parameter1) {
  console.log(parameter1);
};
func();
```

I don't get it why the result should be "undefined". Does the js engine consider parameters as variables? if so what is their variable environment?
Another thing that is confusing me:
Where the anonymous function below is created? where it's hold? and Can it be accessed later in the code?

```js
function a(par1) {
  par1();
}

a(function() {console.log("Hello");)
```

Sorry for the english and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5):

> Every execution context has an associated [VariableEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3).
>   Variables and functions declared in ECMAScript code evaluated in an
>   execution context are added as bindings in that
>   [VariableEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)’s [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1). For function code,
>   parameters are also added as bindings to that [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1).

When you don't specify an argument, the value of the corresponding parameter becomes undefined:

> 1. Let *func* be the function whose [[Call]] internal method initiated execution of *code*. Let *names* be the value of *func*’s
>      [[FormalParameters]] internal property.
> 2. Let *argCount* be the number of elements in *args*.
> 3. Let *n* be the number 0.
> 4. For each String *argName* in *names*, in list order do
>
>    1. Let *n* be the current value of *n* plus 1.
>    2. If *n* is greater than *argCount*, let *v* be **undefined** otherwise let *v* be the value of the *n*’th element of args.

Passing a function expression as an argument is not different than passing anything else. A function object is created according to [13 Function Definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) and [13.2 Creating Function Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2), and that value is passed as an argument. It will be available through a parameter or `arguments`.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are variables that are declared on the function's scope during the compiling phase of the processing.

The undefined result you're getting means the variable exists, but has no value yet. Undefined is its default value.

Read here to understand more about it
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch2.md

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

EDIT: Forgot about your second question.

Anonymous functions are created at the global scope (if they're not inside another scope)and you can't call them again

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are variables within the scope of the function.

The result is `undefined` because unless you explicitly `return` something from your function, the function implicitly returns "undefined".

The anonymous function that you are creating on the fly will only be accessible in the scope of the `a` function as `par1`, just like any other parameter you enter.
Side note: your anonymous function is missing a `}`